# Modify 3-way switch to add circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am a DIYer with electrical wiring experience.  I would like to add an existing secondary light to the 3-way circuit.  The current box has two switches.  The one on the left controls the main light and is part of the 3-way circuit.  The one on the right controls a secondary light.  I would like to remove the switch for the secondary light and have it controlled with the 3-way switch.  The existing wiring is a little confusing.  I have diagrammed it below as best as I can figure it out.  (Ground wires are ignored.)
[image: Wiring Diagram]

[image: Picture]

I would appreciate any advice you could provide.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Colors are usually a hot mess in boxes like this, but by sheer luck, all of your colors are color-coded by function, except the travelers.   I like to mark those yellow (both of them, no need to distinguish one from the other).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question, with good diagram/picture: thanks. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Color coding time

Cables have certain default colors of wires.  We're married to that, so usually trying to "color code wires by function" is a big mess.  But in this case, it works out to be very close. Let's get there.

I want you to **mark both traveler wires with yellow tape** (or another color, just not black, red or white).  No need to distinguish  one from the other. We wont be doing anything with them; I just don't want to confuse them with the wires we will be working with.

Now, remove the switch that is going away.  When you do, you will free up a "pigtail wire".  Remove it from the black bundle (always-hot).   Tape or paint it red.

With the travelers marked, there is one red wire on the 3-way switch.  Remove it and replace it with the red pigtail.

I believe at this point you have three red wires, all loose.  These are switched-hot.   Join them.

*And we're done*.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This makes sense. I will try it out in the next couple days.